# What are the different ways one can use to store form/input/user preferences data on the web site server?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to make small projects to better understand how javascript works and how interactive websites are made. So I wanted to make a simple website that would save links that you would enter using input/form submission. but what are the ways which I can use to store it on the server so when I open the page next time the website retrieves the saved information and displays it? 
I know this question is pretty open, but I'm really lost in this part of web development because I'm seeing too many completely different things on the internet like PHP, ASP.net and what not. Can someone help me out?
It would be very thankful if someone can send me a link to  a related tutorial or some similar resource, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you to do that, you will need a server side program with a Database.
Here is a tutorial for PHP, a popular language to do web pages http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your data in the form, That data will be sent to the file mentioned in the `action` attribute of the form. Now, each input element of your form will have a `name` attribute which you can use to refer as a key in your `GET` or `POST` super global array depending on the method attribute of your form tag.

I know it may sound confusing without example. But, This is explained at many links on the web. Try searching for **form submission with post.**

Answer (score 0):

Decide on which technologies that you want to work with. I prefer you to use ajax with instead of just using javascript.

Link for flask tutorial http://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html

Answer (score 0):

Store the data in the client side is much simple I think. While storage in client, you can use **localStorage** **sessionStorage** and **cookie**.

- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) you can storage whatever you want and it has no expiration time
- [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) the difference between **localStorage** is that it has a expiration time, A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores
- Cookie is much simple and can store limited value in string format